# Parallel vector dot in Python

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, matrix-multiplication

I was trying to use numpy to do the calculations below, where k is an constant and A is a large and dense two-dimensional matrix (40000*40000) with data type of complex128:

```
A = A - k*np.matmul(A[:,0:1],A[1:2,:])
```

It seems either np.matmul or np.dot will only use one core. Furthermore, the subtract operation is also done in one core. I wanted to run this operation on a cluster so am wondering if I can parallel this operation. For a simple test, I separate the two operations to see which is the time costing part.

```
t1 = time.time()
c = np.dot(A_matrix_reverse[:,0:1],A_matrix_reverse[0:1,:])
t2 = time.time()
c = A_matrix_reverse - 10*c
t3 = time.time()
print(t2-t1) # 3.7593634128570557
print(t3-t2) # 9.5412278175354
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, current_process
import time

def func_1(A_1,k_1):
    return A_1 - k_1*np.matmul(A_1[:,0:1],A_1[1:2,:])

def func_2(A_matrix_reverse_2,k_2):
    return np.dot(A_matrix_reverse_2[:,0:1],A_matrix_reverse_2[0:1,:])

A=Process(target=func_1(A,k))
c=Process(target=func_2(A_matrix_reverse,k))

A.start()
c.start()

c=A_matrix_reverse - 10*c
```

Answer (score 0):

Numpy's dot product is run through BLAS, so if you're running it with a multithreaded BLAS library it should be multithreaded. I would suggest trying numpy built against MKL (`python -m pip install intel-numpy`) if for some reason your local BLAS libraries aren't compiled for multithreading.

Also, try the following instead of your current subtraction:

```
c *= -10
c += A_matrix_reverse
```

No need to allocate a bunch of intermediate products you don't want to keep.